# Linking terminal python packages to IDLE python packages

Tags: pip, ubuntu-18.04, python-idle, python-3.7

I have installed python3.7.4 in my ubuntu terminal with all the packages required using pip3.7, Now I need to use IDLE as well but unable to access any package that I have installed using python. The python version in IDLE is 3.7.5 by default as the command I used to install is "sudo apt-get install idle-python3.7". Please specify a way to link all the downloaded packages to the Python IDLE in ubunutu 18.04.

Comment: There are already numerous questions like this.  Answer always the same.  Install 3rd party packages for each python.exe binary you want to run.

Comment: So do I have to install all packages again?, even so how could I because now when I install the packages it referes to the terminal python only and not the IDLE one.

Comment: 1. Yes, but for different 3.7 patch releases, you should probably be able to copy from Lib/site-packages to Lib/site-packages.  2. Did you read answers to previous questions? 3. Each python executable can be run from the terminal, and each can run IDLE if tkinter/IDLE was included.  4. Do you really need both 3.7.4 and 3.7.5?  The latter has more bug fixes.